# Converting a text file into a dictionary in python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, text-files

So, I'm a bit new to Python and I've come across the following problem in one of my codes:

I have a txt file with the following text:

> Jolly 77777
>   Fargo 88888
>   Hunt 68548

I want to convert it into a dictionary with BOTH the name and number as keys... Here's what I have so far but I keep getting a traceback error and am not sure as to what error I am making. It's driving me nuts; Help?

This is what I have so far:

```
filename = open("ident.txt","r")
dictionary={}
with open('ident.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        a,b = line.split()
        dictionary[a] = int(b)
```

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the **full text** of the traceback. Also, if you want both name and number as keys, what are the values supposed to be? Your code is not doing the same thing as what you are saying in the text...

Answer (score 0):

You're close:

```
dictionary = {}
with open('ident.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        a,b = line.split()
        dictionary[a] = int(b)
```

That yields a `dictionary` value of:

```
{'Fargo': 88888, 'Hunt': 68548, 'Jolly': 77777}
```

FWIW, the line `filename = open("ident.txt","r")` isn't going to do you any favors, since `filename` will end up being an open file, not a filename. And you don't need `f.readlines()`. Files iterate fine on their own, line by line.